# How do I split a data array in python into two seperate groupings of variables?

Tags: python, database, text, split

Okay so I'm incredibly new at python and programming and am sorry if this is the wrong format for asking questions

I am trying to group two separate columns from a text document

xy
x1y1
x2y2
ect

into variable classes as in a variable that calls all xs and a variable that calls all ys so they can be iterated in a loop that uses the two separate variables

my coworker has suggested setting up a function similar to this

Data=[]
data.append(line.split(","))

however that will only give a string of XYX1Y1X2Y2 instead of defining all the x values based upon vertical groupings.

Essentially I am asking is there any vertical splitting as opposed to line by line splitting?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rows = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] ; cols = zip(*rows)`?

is that what you are looking for? Its hard to tell what you are asking ...

first split by rows, then convert to columns will be easiest I think

in your case

```
my_2d_list_of_rows = [row.split() for row in my_file]
my_2d_list_of_columns = zip(*my_2d_list_of_rows)
```

Comment: I guess try to imagine an excel spreadsheet where the column is the variable type with each row being a different value. So two variable types with N possible values for the variable differentiated by rows number.

Comment: yeah ... did you run my example code? I think it does what you want... its just not entirely clear ...